# Calling member of one class in another

Tags: c++, function, class

For an assignment I'm required to create a game using die rolls that uses multiple classes. For `Dice.cpp` I i wrote a function that just gets a random die roll from 1 to 6, and then I need to write a separate class that takes the die roll's value and uses it to determine what piece is added in the game, which i did in `player.cpp`. I tried using `#include "Dice.h"` just like i would for main.cpp, but that still tells me that my `d.getRoll()` is not defined in its scope. The takeTurn function is where the problem is, and I'm required to make it void and have no parameters. Any help would be great.

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "Dice.h"

using namespace std;

class player
{
    public:
        player();
        void setPlayerName();
        string getPlayerName();
        void setCootieName();
        string getCootieName();
        void takeTurn();
    private:
        int numLeg, numHead, numEye, numWing, numBody, numAntenna;
        string cootieName;
        string playerName;
        int roll;


};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"


player::player()
{
    numLeg = 0;
    numHead = 0;
    numEye = 0;
    numWing = 0;
    numBody = 0;
    numAntenna = 0;
    cootieName = "Undefined";
    playerName = "Undefined";
}
void player::setPlayerName()
{
    getline(cin, playerName);
}
string player::getPlayerName()
{
    return(playerName);
}
void player::setCootieName()
{
    getline(cin, cootieName);
}
string player::getCootieName()
{
    return(cootieName);
}
void player::takeTurn()
{
    roll = d.getRoll();
    "You rolled a " << roll << "." << endl;
    if (roll == 1)
    {
        numBody++;
    }
    else if (roll == 2)
    {
        numHead++;
    }
    else if (roll == 3)
    {
        numLeg++;
    }
    else if (roll == 4)
    {
        numAntenna++;
    }
    else if (roll == 5)
    {
        numWing++;
    }
    else
    {
        numEye++;
    }
    cout << "Cootie called " << cootieName << " has: " << endl;
    cout << numLeg << " Leg(s)" << endl;
    cout << numHead << " Head(s)" << endl;
    cout << numEye << " Eye(s)" << endl;
    cout << numWing << " Wings(s)" << endl;
    cout << numBody << " Body(s)" << endl;
    cout << numAntenna << " Antenna(s)" << endl;
}
```

Dice.h

```
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Dice
{
    public:
        Dice(int, int);
        int getRoll();
    private:
        int rollTop, rollBot;
};

#endif // DICE_H
```

Dice.cpp

```
#include "Dice.h"

Dice::Dice(int bot, int top)
{
    rollBot = bot;
    rollTop = top;
}
int Dice::getRoll()
{
    return(rand() % rollTop + rollBot);
}
```

EDIT: Here's the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "Dice.h"
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int playerChoice;
    Dice d(1,6);
    player p;

    cout << "Enter player name" << endl;
    p.setPlayerName();
    cout << "Your name is " << p.getPlayerName() << "." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Time to create a Cootie!" << endl;
    cout << "Please name your Cootie!" << endl;
    p.setCootieName();
    cout << "Add body parts using die rolls." << endl;
    cout << "To roll the die, input 1" << endl;
    cout << "To exit, input 0" << endl;
    cin >> playerChoice;
    while(1)
    {
        if (playerChoice == 1)
        {
            p.takeTurn();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `d`? Where is that variable declared and defined?

Comment: And you are missing a parenthesis pair after the getRoll call.

Comment: Woops, fixed the parenthesis. `d` is declared near the top of main.cpp in `Dice d(1,6);` Its part of my Dice class.

Comment: I declared the `d` before i used the player class, do i need to declare that elsewhere?

Comment: Gotta declare it outside main(), non-static, if that is what you are trying to do. Better way is to include it in player or pass it in to the constructor.

Comment: How might i include it in player? just declare it there in `private:` like the other variables?

Comment: yep, dont forget to configure it during constructor.

Comment: Some tips about Dice.h: you should never do "using namespace" in a header file.  And you should name the constructor parameters, because Dice(int, int) is a real mystery.

Comment: So i should just do std:: instead? And thanks, still new to this. Also, i still don't quite understand how to declare my `Dice d(1,6)` in a way that works

Answer (score 1):

You need to either create an instance of `Dice` to call the method on like this

```
Dice d;
roll = d.getRoll();
```

or you need to make getRoll static. In the function declaration in Dice.h you'd put

```
static int getRoll();
```

and you would use it like this

```
roll = Dice::getRoll();
```